# Apache rewriteRule to check login and redirect to page

Tags: perl, apache

This is a follow up for this question [Apache directory directive authentication based on Perl CGI::Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892270/apache-directory-directive-authentication-based-on-perl-cgisession)

```
 Alias /files /myData/all
<Directory /myData/all >
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cgi-bin/checklogin.pl?url=/files/$1 [L,R]
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

/files is a directory listing.

I edited the directive so that if a user  goes to webserver/files/  they are redirected to checklogin.pl which checks for the existance of a session. If there is one it should redirect to the ?url if not it takes them to the loginpage.

The first part works. The redirect to $url causes a loop.

```
my $url = $cgi->param("url");
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie('mysession');
if(!$cookie){
        $session = new CGI::Session();
        print $session->redirect('/loginpage.html');
}else{
     # HOW DO I display folder or files now?
      $session  = new CGI::Session(undef, $cookie, {Directory=>'/tmp/'});
      print $session->redirect($url);
}
```

I am, obviously, getting a redirect loop error in Apache

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

Comment: Why are you setting your cookie to expire immediately?

Comment: it's irrelevant I've removed it, in that case there is not existing cookie

Comment: You don't include your cookie in the response headers so the user will never get it.

Comment: fixed. I was trying to keep irrelevant code out.

Comment: Have you checked that `loginpage.html` sets the cookie correctly?

Comment: yes cookies are working fine everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect every request to `checklogin.pl`, any requests made *inside* `checklogin.pl` will redirect to `checklogin.pl`, which will redirect to `checklogin.pl`, which will redirect to `checklogin.pl`...

Instead, why don't you make a master script with a `logged_in` function that you call with each request:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

sub logged_in {
    # Check session
}

my $q = CGI->new;

if (not logged_in()) {
    print $q->redirect('http://url/to/login.html'); # Need to use a full URL
}
else {
    # Do stuff
}
```

Comment: /files is not a script directly but contains files. Not scripts my session works fine for the rest of the site, I need a way to restrict access to directories

Comment: This *does* restrict access to directories; users can't do anything that you don't put in the `else` block. I think what you're *really* asking is how to do user-based access control with Apache (since you want to show directory listings). You could, of course, print the contents of a particular directory in your Perl script.

Comment: How can I print the contents of a the directory in Perl so that the files are clickable

Comment: If the user-supplied path maps to a directory (I say "maps" because users should not be able to control the exact location on your filesystem, just as with Apache's `Alias`), and the user has access to it, use `readdir` or [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) to get the directory contents and print a link to each one. If the path is a file, open it and print the contents.