# php loading/displaying a image

Tags: php, image, iis

I am hoping someone can help me, I am wanting to load/display a image on a page using php.
But I want disable the images folder from been accessed from the web.

so e.g if I go to /image.php/test.jpg
I want it to go get that image from the image folder and show it on screen using the image.php file, but I don't want it to be viewable like this http://website.com/images/test.jpg (i dont need help with the link code or anything, just the code needed instead of the html img tag)
at the moment I am putting the img tage into a varible then returning it out of the function, but I don't think that will work this will work when I close up the image folder.

I am using iis8, I know how to disable the access using request filtering and setting the folder in url deny, just cant get the images or css file to load when I do that, unless theres a better/easier way to do it using iis so only php could call the files but guests cant using my existing

Many thanks all, Michael.

Comment: Are you displaying other content on the page or just the one image?

Comment: So image.php is entirely responsible for outputting image data? Then use the url to the file as the src attribute: `<img src="image.php/test.jpg"/>` As to how you lock down the images folder, the easiest thing is to place it outside the webroot

Comment: See this post, you can know how to protect your images being accessed.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416736

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to password protect files (images, video, zip) dynamically from public and allow access to members only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416736/how-to-password-protect-files-images-video-zip-dynamically-from-public-and-a)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this in your `.htaccess` file (assuming your images are located in `/images`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /images/
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.jpg)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Then create an `index.php` in your images folder and put the logic in there to serve the image.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] === "mywebsite.com"){
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile($_GET['p']);
}
```

Or if you simply want to disable indexing, [Google is full of helpful info](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/).

Comment: `(.+?\.pdf)` shouldn't that be a jpg file?

Answer (score 0):

Add a .htaccess file in your images folder (AllowOverride must be set to true) with the following content:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

then create your image.php

```
$img = $_GET['img'];

$file = 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $img;
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

readfile($file);
```

and your html should look like:

```
<img src="image.php?img=rick-rolled.jpg">
```

Comment: To the down-voter: It would be courteous to explain your downvote so that everybody learns something.

Comment: I did not downvote and Mark is right. However, I think the downvote was because of `$img = $_GET['img'];` that should be `$img = $_GET['file'];` since calling it with `image.php?file` or `$img = $_GET['img'];` with `image.php?img`

Comment: if you're not worried about hotlinking and you only want to disable indexing, there is no need to get PHP involved.

Comment: @Adelphia You know, I could have easily also downvoted your answer with the error you made, but I didn't. I made a comment about the `.pdf`. You could have done the same and have said something. There's a lesson here (wink) we're here to help each other, not compete.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't downvote because of the error, I didn't notice it. I downvoted because the intended solution is inefficient and unnecessary. Not to say it won't work.

Comment: @Adelphia Why did you not say that first? You say it now, only "after" the fact.The answer could have been improved. Silent downvoters drive me crazy also lol am sure it would you too, if someone downvotes you but doesn't say why.

Comment: Fred, Montanelu, Sorry for the delay in explaining my downvote. It was only because I noticed Fred's comment on my answer and wantedd to fix my own error first. I have removed my downvote.

Comment: thanks guys will have a look later on and let you know, how would the htaccess stuff be done on iis8?

Comment: right I have locked down the folder and I cant get it to work using readfile, my old code was as follows:  $return .=  '<a href="'.$file_values["file"].'"><img src="'.$file_values["file"].'" alt="'.$file_values["title"].'" title="'.$file_values["title"].'"></a>'."\n"; it was using $return for all the content I need to display from that current function and then using return $return; I am guessing its something to do with this, that's causing it not to work.