# URL handling – PHP vs Apache Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite

Currently I let a single PHP script handle all incoming URLs. This PHP script then parses the URL and loads the specific handler for that URL. Like this:

```
if(URI === "/")
{
    require_once("root.php");
}
else if(URI === "/shop")
{
    require_once("shop.php");
}
else if(URI === "/contact")
{
    require_once("contact.php");
}

...

else
{
    require_once("404.php");
}
```

Now, I keep thinking that this is actually highly inefficient and is going to need a lot of unnecessary processing power once my site is being visited more often. So I thought, why not do it within Apache with mod_rewrite and let Apache directly load the PHP script:

```
RewriteRule ^$ root.php [L]
RewriteRule ^shop$ shop.php [L]
...
```

However, because I have a lot of those URLs, I only want to make the change if it really is worth it.

So, here's my question: What option is better (efficiency-wise and otherwise) and why?

Btw, I absolutely want to keep the URL scheme and not simply let the scripts accessible via their actual file name (something.php).

Comment: How are you dealing with static resources like style sheets and images? As long as those don't get passed through the PHP script, it's probably okay

Comment: @Pekka, well they are, because some resources are only available to logged in users, so I get to check cookies and login state first, then I serve them with readfile(). But thank you for actually providing the first real answer to my problem.

Comment: by the way you should be using `switch - case`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, here's my question: What option is better (efficiency-wise and otherwise) and why?

If every resource has to run through a PHP based check, as you say in your comment:

> some resources are only available to logged in users, so I get to check cookies and login state first, then I serve them with readfile().

then you can indeed use PHP-side logic to handle things: A PHP instance is going to be started anyway, which renders the performance improvement of parsing URLs in Apache largely moot.

If you have static resources that do *not* need any session or other PHP-side check, you should absolutely handle the routing in the .htaccess file if possible, because you avoid starting a separate PHP process for every resource. But in your case, that won't apply.

Some ideas to increase performance:

- consider whether really *every* resource needs to be protected through PHP-based authentication. Can style sheets or some images not be public, saving the performance-intensive PHP process?
- try minifying resources into as few files as possible, e.g. by minifying all style sheets into one, and using CSS sprites to reduce the number of images.
- I've heard that [nginx](http://nginx.org/) is better prepared to handle this specific kind of scenario - at least I'm told it can very efficiently handle the delivery of a file after the authentication check has been done, instead of having to rely on PHP's `readfile()`.

Comment: @unicorn no problem. I asked a very similar question once: [Performance-oriented way to protect files on PHP level?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1688568) the answers suggest that there is no really *good* way to solve this - if you want performance, you have to expose your resources to the public, if you want security, you have to run the request through a PHP check every time

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

and rename `root.php` to `index.php`.

Comment: it wouldn't - [a-z]+ would not match dot in it

Comment: Next time, it'd be really nice if you actually **read** the question. This isn't an answer. And your single line won't work in my case because I use dynamic URLs like /item/2839/page3. The examples I provided are just a stripped down version of what I am doing, stripped of all unnecessary noise for this question.

Comment: right, my bad, but it won't catch foo-bar, foo_bar or similarities either.

Comment: @unicornop - just modify regexp to match all URLs. we are not phophets to know how they look like

Comment: you don't need to be a prophet to read my question, to which you haven't provided any answer.

Comment: there is nothing in your question related to that. if it is - name it

Comment: I quote from a few lines above: _So, here's my question: What option is better (efficiency-wise and otherwise) and why?_ I haven't asked you to code my .htaccess file for me. I just want to know which of the two ways to handle URIs (through one PHP script, or through mod_rewrite) is better and why. Your original answer, which only provided one line with a RewriteRule hasn't answered that question.

Comment: @unicorn you have to admit though that your question isn't 100% perfect either. For example, the information that you are passing static resources through this front controller as well is vital, and should have been there in the first place

Comment: Well, I say that right in the first sentence: _Currently I let a **single** PHP script handle **all** incoming URLs._

Comment: @unicorn fair enough, although more emphasis ("*including* images etc.") wouldn't hurt. Anyway, it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

The PHP approach is correct but it could use a bit of improvement.

```
$file = $uri.".php";
if (!is_file($file)) { header("Status: 404 Not Found"); require_once(404.php); die(); }
require_once($uri.".php");
```

Comment: Won't work for the same reasons I explained in comment #3 to Jacek_FH's answer. Again, the example URIs I provided aren't what I'm using, but that shouldn't be a problem if someone actually read the question.

Comment: I've read your question thoroughly and I fail to see where my answer is not sufficient. If you think you oversimplified your question, why don't you post a more actual example of your code?

Comment: So, how would I handle /items/34893/page3 with your code? I can with mine (e.g. using an if statement with substr(URI, 0, 7) === '/items/' or preg_match).

Comment: And two different URLs might actually use the same handler, e.g. /items and /cheap-items/

Comment: Well, in that case my code will include "items/34893/page3.php", which does not contradicts anything you've asked in your question, again, please elaborate if there are any further rules for it. As for your original question, I think PHP would be better then using ModRewrite on this one.

Comment: _As for your original question, I think PHP would be better then using ModRewrite on this one._ OK. Why?

Comment: It's a point of view really. I generally dislike using ModRewrite, and PHP seems to be able to do it rather easily. I think ModRewrite should only be used in some VERY general cases.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as for efficiency - htaccess version with regexp and php version with single regexp and loading of matching file would be faster than many htaccess rules or many php if - else

Apart from that, htaccess and php way should be similar in efficiency in that case, probably with little gain with htaccess (eliminating one require in php)

Comment: I disagree with your last sentence. With PHP, a complete instance has to be started, memory reserved, sessions started, etc. It can become quite a resource hog if not used carefully. Where sensible, it's best to use Apache's logic.

Comment: but php will be loaded at the end after all - it's one php load in both cases

Comment: not necessarily if the requested resource is a static one. (Other than that, you're correct.)