# Use long list of .htaccess RewriteRule or use a single catchall and direct in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say im using .htaccess file for clean looking links, but that I have a long list (say 20) of RewriteRules to do things like this

```
domain.com/user/adam --> domain.com/user.php?need=user&user=adam
domain.com/test.js --> domain.com/index.php?need=code&file=test.js
domain.com/test.js/edit --> domain.com/index.php?need=code&file=test.js&action=edit
```

Is it better to use a catch all RewriteRule and split on the slash/ parse and direct in PHP? Or is the long list of RewriteRule better?

Better I guess I mean faster, and more robust. I know that upkeep would be better with the catch all.

Also, can you recommend a php class example/article on doing this?

Comment: Are u using any frameworks? Using MVC?

Comment: This is very close to my own question ;)

Here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702667/php-handling-vs-apache-rewriterules-and-regexp-which-one-is-quicker

Comment: It is being implemented using MVC methods, but im not using a framework.

Comment: Whatever works for you is fine. If you find yourself having to change/add rules frequently it might be better to find a more generic solution, like a catch-all. 20 rules is not a lot, when you are talking about performance. I would not worry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at ZendRouter - even though you're not using a framework, you may want to follow their ideas.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Essentially .htaccess routes all requests to the index.php file with the exception of any matches to the RegEx:

```
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$ index.php
```

Or any non files / directories (though I think there is a slightly higher cost to check if a file/directory exists rather than regex the requested URL)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Once you've leveraged this type of routing - you can define a standard regex for URLs to map to controllers/actions

Answer (score 1):

If this answers what your asking, there is no problem using a massive list of rewrite rules. I have seen rewrite rules that fill my whole monitor and then some - there is no problem with a massive list unless you have a problem with them.