# changing url name and what file it points to in php

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, content-management-system

I'm new to web development but i know some php basic stuff. Using ftp, i create directories then create simple php scripts there, simple as echoing a string. Which can be accessed like,

> www.sampledomain.com/folder1/subfolder2/hello.php

After some time, my friend introduced me to wordpress which is what they described as CMS. I tried to visit her site [www.majaflores.com](http://www.majaflores.com) then i click on some stuff there and i noticed the url changed to http://majaflores.com/project/if-i-let-you-in-please-dont-break-anything/

At first, its pretty normal for me because its just a link where there is a folder named **"project"** and inside it another folder named **"if-i-let-you-in-please-dont-break-anything"**. But when she showed me the ftp folders directory, i didnt see any folder named "**project**" under main folder of the domain. How did wordpress manage to do this? and how can i implement this manually?

Comment: It's called url rewriting. There are no directories involved. Look up `.htacces` rewrite rules. Windows has a similar file called `web.config`.

Comment: you mean i can create a virtual folder using .htaccess? okay gonna check it

Comment: Yeah sort of. You feed it that url and the site translates it to something like `www.example.com?section=project&title=if-i-let-you-in-please-dont-break-anything` then the database pulls up that row with those criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to say that like most server-side code environments, PHP also let you parse URLs "manually" and decide what to do accordingly, be it return a file or generate some content.

You can find more information about how PHP is parsing URLs in here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

and some discussion regarding it in here:

[URL handling – PHP vs Apache Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961483/url-handling-php-vs-apache-rewrite)

Answer (score 1):

This is they way WordPress stores data. U can further see the setting under Permalink.

Under Permalink, u can have options to render ulr as page id, category names and more. You can also use your own format over there.

Just a note, WordPress stored data in database not as a content on FTP directory.